# Probability measure under measure space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove this question and my doubt is the $a_i$ works like a weight and needs to sum=1.
Thanks

Be $\Bbb P_1, \Bbb P_2,..., \Bbb P_n$ probability measure under $(\Omega,A)$ and $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ real numbers with   $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 1$. Define the set function $\Bbb P$ as
$$ 
\Bbb P(A) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \Bbb P_k(A),
$$
and $A \in \mathcal A$. Show that $ \Bbb P$ is a probability measure under $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$.

Comment: Do $a_i\ge 0$ for every $i$?

Comment: Which property of a probability measure you are unable to verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a_i\ge 0$ and each $\Bbb P_k$ is a probability measure (so they all are nonnegative) we have $\Bbb P(A) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \Bbb P_k(A)\ge 0\quad\forall A\in\mathcal A$.

Since $a_1+\ldots+a_n=1$ and $\Bbb P_k(\Omega)=1$ for each $k$, $\Bbb P(A) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \Bbb P_k(\Omega)=a_1+\ldots+a_n=1$.

Finally, consider $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ a countable family of sets of $\cal A$. Then $\Bbb P(\cup_{i\in I}A_i)=\sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \Bbb P_k(\cup_{i\in I}A_i)= \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \big(a_k\sum_{i\in I} \Bbb P_k(A_i)\big)=\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \big(\sum_{i\in I} a_k\Bbb P_k(A_i)\big)=\sum_{i\in I}\big(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\Bbb P_k(A_i)\big)=\sum_{i\in I}\Bbb P(A_i)$, with the secon last equality holding because the sum is absolutely convergent (it is convergent because it's just a finite sum of probabilities of sets, and it does it absolutely because it is a positive sum).

Therefore $\Bbb P$ satisfies all three axioms of the definition, so it's a probability measure.